# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in TABLE when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF; .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to clone entities in EF Core. As far as I understand, I need to retrieve them AsNoTracking and then re-add them however when I do I get the error:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in Exercises
>   when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF;

I added the data annotation: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` to the Id but I'm still getting the same error.

Here is my code:

```
public class Exercise : Entity
{
    public Exercise()
    {
        Sets = new HashSet<Set>();
    }       

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int MuscleGroupId {get;set;}

    public int MesoId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Set> Sets { get; set; }

    public void AddSet(Set set)
    {
        Sets.Add(set);
    }
}
```

And here is my code for Entity which has I set an annotation telling EF Core the ID is database generated:

```
 public class Entity
 {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
 }
```

Here is the code to clone the entities:

```
 var exercises = _context.Exercises.AsNoTracking().Include(y => y.Sets)
.Where(x => x.MesoId == mesoId && x.Date == fromDate);

 foreach (var exercise in exercises)
   {
      exercise.Date = toDate;
      _context.Exercises.Add(exercise);
   }

 await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: You cannot actually clone the `Entity` rows because `Id` is an identity column. i.e.: you cannot supply `Id` values when inserting new `Entity` rows. What happens if you change the attribute to `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]`?

Comment: I get the same error :( I thought if you add the AsNonTracking it ensure EF sees everything as new entities and then I add them with the data annotation        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] so EF doesn't try to insert the ID. @AlwaysLearning

Comment: You need to set the value of Id property to 0 before doing `_context.Exercises.Add(exercise)`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the problem is I have to go down the entire object graph setting all the entity Ids to 0. I thought the [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] annotation would prevent me from having to do that.

Comment: Sql server throws this exception coz the primary key column has already value assigned value. So until you set it to zero you can not get rid of the error. You can write clone method for all the classes involved in the graph and call them top-down and copy all the properties except primary key property.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot store values into an Identity column in the database because that value is managed by the database itself.

When "cloning" your Exercise records you need to set `Id=0` so that when the new row gets inserted the database will create the Identity value for it, e.g.:

```cs
foreach (var exercise in exercises)
{
   exercise.Date = toDate;
   exercise.Id = 0; //<<--This is important!
   _context.Exercises.Add(exercise);
}
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I have an Include for the Sets so I would need to set each and every Set to Set.Id = 0 and then if they have relationships I have to do that for them as well all through the object graph. Is there an easier way?